# Show jquery jsonp callback result

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Sorry as my question stupid and elementary....

how write jsonp callback result to page, I'm trying such with jquery but result - Data Saved: [object Object]

```
function alertResponse(text) {
document.write( "Data Saved: " + text );
}


$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'alertResponse'
});
```

the rusult by url is

```
jsonp1293628807768({"text":"  <div class=\"package_search_result_table\" 710px>\r\n    <div class=\"itt_title\" style=\"width: 710px;\">\r\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON](http://www.json.org/js) library and it's `JSON.stringify` function to display the text.

Answer (score 2):

jsonpCallback is a way to know the name of the function that will handle the callback.  It's not supposed to **be** the callback function!  You ought to try `complete: alertResponse`

Answer (score 0):

If you want jQuery to call a specific function you must add `jsonp: false`. Writing only `jsonpCallback` is useless

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'alertResponse'
});
```